# Solution verification: Proving that this language is irregular using the pumping lemma.

Tags: solution-verification, regular-language, pumping-lemma

> Prove that the following language with $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, is not regular using the pumping lemma: 
> $L=\{ba^{2^{k}}b^{i_1}ab^{i_2}...b^{i_k}a : k\ge 1, \forall j\space\space (1\le j \le k)\space\space i_j\ge 1  \}$

At first I tried to understand what is the language, so I tried to write a word that is in it: 
$ba^{2^2}b^5ab^6a=baaaabbbbbabbbbbba$. 
So I can say that theres $k$ - $(b^+a)$ to the right of $ba^{2^k}$.

Let's assume by contradiction that $L$ is regular, then the pumping lemma works on it, so there exists a constant $n$, where for every word $z\in L$ that satisfies $|z|\ge n$, we can write $z=uvw$ and: 
$|uv|\le n$, $|v|\ge 1$, $uv^iw\in L\space\space\space \forall i\ge 0$.

Let $z=ba^{2^n}(ba)^n$, (n is the constant of the lemma). 
There's two possibilities: 
1- $u=ba^s, v=a^{t}\space\space t\ge 1, w=a^{2^n-s-t}(ba)^n$. 
2- $u = \epsilon, v=ba^t \space\space t\ge 0, w=a^{2^n-t}(ba)^n$ 
for (1), $uv^iw=ba^sa^{ti}a^{2^n-s-t}(ba)^n=ba^{2^n+t(i-1)}(ba)^n$
if we choose $i=2^n+1$, then $ba^{2^n+t2^n}(ba)^n\in L$. But 
$2^n+t2^n\ge 2^n+2^n\ge 2^{n+1}$, which gives us a contradiction, since $(ba)^n$ needs to be $(ba)^{n+1}$ atleast for this word to have a chance to be in $L$.

For (2), $uv^iw=(ba^t)^ia^{2^n-t}(ba)^n$, We choose $i=0$ and get that: 
$a^{2^n-t}(ba)^n\in L$, which is a contradiction since it doesn't start with $b$. 
So I've shown that for every possibility, we reach a contradiction when we assume $L$ is regular, so it is irregular.
Any feedback is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying the pumping lemma, you could use the following argument.
Let
$$
K = L \cap ba^+(ba)^+ = \{ba^{2^k}(ba)^k \mid k > 0\}
$$
If $L$ is regular, then so is $K$, as the intersection of two regular languages. Let now $\pi: \{a,b\}^* \to a^*$ be the monoid homomorphism that erases the $b$'s. Then
$$
\pi(K) = \{a^{k + 2^k} \mid k > 0 \}
$$
is also regular, since regular languages are closed under homomorphisms.
And now you can get a contradiction by proving that $\pi(K)$ is not regular, using the pumping lemma if you wish.

EDIT. Your proof is carefully written and works well. You could also take $i = 2$ in case (1). Indeed, since $t < n$, you would get $2^n < 2^n + t < 2^n + n \leqslant 2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. This shows that $2^n + t$ is not a power of $2$ and hence $ba^{2^n + t}(ba)^n$ is not in $L$.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, it taught me new ideas of how to deal with these questions! But this particular question requests to be proven only using the pumping lemma, it's my bad for not stating that clearly, but I really appreciate the trick you used to solve it and it really improved my understanding. If you could approve if my proof works well or any feedback about it I would really appreciate it!

Comment: #Pwaol You're welcome. I have edited my answer and added a comment on your proof.